# Celcius to Fahrenheit(vice versa) using Range

Tags: python, range

Good day everyone, I would like to ask what to add to make converting to Celcius to Fahrenheit(vice versa) using Range..

Use the relationship in degree size to convert between Celsius and Fahrenheit. Because Celsius degrees are larger than those in Fahrenheit, to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit, multiply the Celsius temperature by 1.8, then add 32. Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit using the following equation:

F = (1.8 x C) + 32

You can also use this formula to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius. To convert the Fahrenheit temperature, first subtract 32, then divide the result by 1.8.

C = (F - 32)/1.8

Using for loop create a program that converts temperature either from Celsius to Fahrenheit or vice versa.

1. ```
     Ask the user what will be the input of the user either in Celsius or Fahrenheit. If the input is invalid, print invalid and ask to try again.
   ```
2. ```
     Ask the user to input the start, range, and interval separated by an asterisk. For example 0*10*2. This means that the start of the conversion will be from 0 to 10 with an interval of 2, thus the value to be converted will be 0, 3, 6, 9
   ```

If the start<end, then the interval should be 0<interval otherwise, your program will display an error and ask to try again for #2. Or

If the start>end, then the interval should be 0>interval otherwise, your program will display an error and ask to try again for #2.

If the user inputs only one value, like 10. This means that the start is equal to 1 which will be the default value for start, up to 10, and the interval is 2 which will be the default value of the interval if start<end.

If the user input has two values like 10*2, this means that the start is equal to 10 up to 2. The interval is set to the default value which is equal to -2 since start>end.

```
the input should be: depending on your interval range.. example 0*20*3
Celcius   Fahrenheit
0          32.0
4          39.2
8          46.4
12         53.6
16         60.8
20         68.0
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

answer1_flag = 0 while answer1_flag == 0:
    ask = input("What would you like to choose?  Celcius = 1, Fahrenheit = 2. \nPick option 1 or 2: ").strip()

    if ask == '1' or ask == '2':
        answer1_flag = 1
        answer2_flag = 0
        while answer2_flag == 0:
            rng = input("Enter the start, range, interval. \n example 0*10*2:").strip()
            count = rng.count('*')
            if count == 0:
                start = 1
                end = int(rng)
                interval = 2
            elif count == 1:
                start, end = map(int, rng.split("*"))
                if start < end:
                    interval = 2
                elif start > end:
                    interval = -2
            elif count == 2:
                start, end, interval = map(int, rng.split("*"))



            if start > end and interval > 0:
                print('Error! If start>end then interval should be a negative number! Please enter the input again.')
            elif start < end and interval < 0:
                print('Error! If start<end then interval should be a positive number! Please enter the input again.')
            else:
                rng = range(start, end, interval)
                answer2_flag = 1
    else:
        print('Invalid! Try again.')

print(rng)
```

Comment: You want to ask how to write the program and then you show the program – what exactly is your question then?

Comment: Do you know how a `for` loop works? Here you'll need something like `for temperature in range(start, end, interval)`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the guide... and I'm very sorry for the confusing question. It seems that i forgot to add the for loop, thank you so much once again sir